# iTextSharp extraer texto de pdf por coordenadas

Tags: c#, pdf

Estoy intentando extraer el texto de un pdf por coordenadas de forma visual

```
public override void BeginGetText(Image page, uint pageNumber)
        {
            _PageNumber = (int)pageNumber;

            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FileName))
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle mediabox = reader.GetPageSize((int)pageNumber);
                //iTextSharp.text.Rectangle cropbox = reader.GetCropBox((int)pageNumber);

                _FactorX = page.Width / (mediabox.Width + 0.0F);
                _FactorY = page.Height / (mediabox.Height + 0.0F);
            }
        }
```

De esa forma obtengo el factor de conversión, pero lo he puesto a 72p para que sea 1 (por lo que eso no es)

```
public override string GetText(int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FileName))
            {
                float
                    fx = x / _FactorX, fy = y / _FactorY,
                    fw = w / _FactorX, fh = h / _FactorY;

                System.util.RectangleJ rect = new System.util.RectangleJ(fx, fy, fw, fh);

                ITextExtractionStrategy textExtractionStrategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(),
                    new RenderFilter[] { new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect) });


                string ret = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, _PageNumber, textExtractionStrategy);
                return ret;
            }
        }
```

y de esta forma lo extraigo, el problema es que no me devuelve el texto de esas posiciones, de hecho si le pongo toda la página (588x842) si que me lo saca, pero si le pongo desde 0,0 hasta 588,400 para sacar la mitad superior, me saca la inferior.

¿Alguna idea? solo consigo que funcione si le pongo pagina completa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo resolví utilizando pdfbox para este propósito.

```
public override string GetText(int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            decimal 
                fx = x / _FactorX, fy = y / _FactorY,
                fw = w / _FactorX, fh = h / _FactorY;

            lock (_Page)
            {
                PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
                stripper.addRegion("testRegion", new java.awt.Rectangle((int)fx, (int)fy, (int)fw, (int)fh));
                stripper.extractRegions(_Page);

                string ret = stripper.getTextForRegion("testRegion");
                if (ret == null) return "";
                return ret.Trim();
            }
        }
```

Comment: El problema que ocurre con los pdf es que el punto 0,0 no es arriba a la izquierda sino abajo a la izquierda, es decir las coordenadas verticales están invertidas. Para sacar la mitad superior deberias pedir desde el 0,858 hasta el
588,400. Me alegro que lo solucionaras Saludetes